# Octave surface plot with rectangular grid, no triangles

Tags: octave

When I run the Octave-Script (Octave 4.0.3 on Linux)

```
frequencies = 1:8;
times = 1:80;
for t=times
    for f=frequencies
        field(f,t) = abs( cos(f*0.3)*cos(pi*t*0.1) );
    end
end

figure;
surface( times, frequencies, field );
% xlim( [0,70] );

saveas( gcf, 'test.png', 'png' );
```

I get a surface plot with most color fields in a rectangle, but some rectangles are split into two triangles of different colors.

[image]

This looks ugly to my eyes.

I tried to play with options and realised that the triangles go away when I plot only a smaller region (uncomment the `xlim` statement) of the data.

Is there any way to plot all data without the triangular color-areas and only rectangles?

Comment: looks like a OpenGL tesselation problem? What GPU driver do you have and can you try preloading a software renderer. I guess you are using an OpenGL toolkit (fltk or qt?) or gnuplot. Btw, there is no need to use surface here, just use `imagesc`

Comment: @Andy: Your guess is correct, OpenGL via fltk (the default). Using your hint, I then tried `graphics_toolkit( 'gnuplot' )` and get the irritating triangles, as well. The command `imagesc` creates nice rectangles and I will try to proceed in that direction. Thanks.

Comment: I can reproduce your problem with the OpenGL toolkits but swithcing to `graphics_toolkit gnuplot` gives me the correct output. Do you have closed all figures, for example with `close all` before executing your code again?

Comment: @Andy: Thanks, indeed, this brings me one big step further. I see the correct figure and all would be fine… Until I add a colorbar: `close all;
graphics_toolkit( 'gnuplot' );
figure;
surface( times, frequencies, field );
colorbar( 'EastOutside' );` and run in traditional mode: `octave-cli -q --traditional test.m`. Then `saveas` fails: `error: nth_element: n must be a scalar or a contiguous range
error: called from
    median at line 84 column 12
    __gnuplot_print__ at line 37 column 20
    print at line 429 column 14
    saveas at line 105 column 3
    test.m at line 15 column 1`

Comment: I never used --traditional, whats the reasaon? If you omitt --traditional, does it work?

Comment: Without --traditional it works. I find it strange that `saveas` does not work with --traditional, but this problem is different from the original problem with the surface command. So the original problem is solved now. Thanks a lot!